# Accessing functions of a class not working

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++ and am complete newbie, sorry in advance if the question will sound stupid

I have my program to solve Two Sum problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(const vector<int>& a, int target) {
        unordered_map<int, int> valueToIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); i++) {
            auto it = valueToIndex.find(target - a[i]);
            if (it != valueToIndex.end()) {
                return { it->second,i };
            }
            valueToIndex[a[i]] = i;
        }
        throw invalid_argument("sum not found");
    }
};
int main()
{
    vector<int> a{ 11,22,33,44,55 };
    int target_value = 55;
    Solution A;
    A.twoSum(a,target_value);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile my program using test input values console returns nothing

What could be the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Well maybe that's because you didn't write any code that would actually show you something? Can you point your finger at the exact line in the shown code you believe will "show" some output, any kind of output? You forgot The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "Your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". You never told your computer to show any output, so it doesn't.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your reply! I thought return past in TwoSum function should've done it but I might have been wrong. Could you please suggest what could be done in order to achieve the result? I tried cout<<A.twoSum(a,target_value)<<endl; but for some reason it's not compiling and visual studio underline cout <<

Comment: No, it doesn't compile "for some reason", but for a specific reason. The function returns a `std::vector`. There is no defined `<<` overload for a `std::ostream` and `std::vector`. C++ does not work this way. You must write the code to take the returned vector, and format it and show it, in whichever way you want. This is entirely up to you, how you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstable, if you have a function that returns something, you need to get that return.
 In your example, like that

```
vector<int> myResult = A.twoSum(a,target_value);
```

Then you can use that result like that.

```
for (const auto &value : myResult)
       std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

Comment: for (const auto &value : myResult)
       std::cout << value << std::endl; worked but is it possible to return in vector form?

Comment: What do you mean ? This way, you return in vector form and iterate on it to print each element. You can't just print the whole vector like that.